# sound control smoke particle

Tags: particles, audio

---

I try to create a music, and I would like to do  a simple animation , just a black background with some smoke on the front that would be animated  following the sound of the track, I have no idea how I can achieve this, but I know this community is huge and I hope someone can give me a clue with something I can start with, thank you :)

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on YouTube for this... search for "Audio React" and you will find plenty of step by step info.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAes-ITNaGA&ab_channel=quollism) is a great Youtube tutorial on using the 'bake sound to f-curves' to drive animation, starting with very basic movements based on the sound graph to being able to control different parts of animation based on different stems of audio. It uses Blender v2.79 but I recently followed along using v2.82 and it is still very comprehendible.